# grep -P to find lines containing exactly n A's followed by exactly n B's

Tags: regex, unix, grep, pcre, pcregrep

Is it possible to write a `grep -P` (PCRE) command that prints the lines containing only `A` and `B` such that there are exactly *n* `A`'s followed by exactly *n* `B`'s and no other characters. Such that these are valid matches:

```
AB
AAABBB
AAAAAAABBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

while these are not:

```
AAABB
ABBBBBB
BBBA
ABABA
BBBBBBBB
```

Comment: Please rephrase as a question. Also, you have perl tagged but this is a grep question.

Comment: It might be possible but have you tried anything?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Indeed, an exact duplicate as @JamesBrown linked.  With a valid answer there. Voted to close

Answer (score 3):

With normal regular expressions, you can't do this - they can only match regular context-free languages (Type 3 in the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) of languages), while what you want to match is a classic example of a type 2 language.

Luckily, `perl` regular expressions aren't very regular in the formal language theory sense. You can match this using a [recursive regular expression](https://regular-expressions.mobi/recurse.html?wlr=1):

```sh
$ perl -ne 'print if /^((?>A(?1)B|))$/' input.txt
AB
AAABBB
AAAAAAABBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
$ grep -P '^((?>A(?1)B|))$' input.txt  
AB
AAABBB
AAAAAAABBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

(Where `input.txt` contains all your test cases).

This matches either an empty string (0 A's followed by 0 B's), or a string starting with A, a successful recursive match of the pattern against the rest of the string minus the first and last characters, and ending with a B. If a B appears before an A, an A after a B, or the total number of A's and B's don't match, it thus fails. `(?>regex)` is [an optimization](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html?wlr=1) that prevents backtracking after a match failure.

If you want to enforce `n >= 1`, a slight variation to lift one pair of A and B  outside of the recursive section: `^A((?>A(?1)B|))B$`.